# How to resize images with PHP PARSE SDK

Tags: php, image, parsing, resize

I want to upload resized images with PARSE. ¿I don't now how I can do that. This is the code which I'm uploading images.

```
if ( isset( $_FILES['image'] ) ) {

    // save file to Parse
    $file = ParseFile::createFromData( file_get_contents( $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'] ), $_FILES['image']['name']  );
    $file->save();
}

$report = new ParseObject("Report");

$report->set("ImageFile", $file);
$report->save();
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors? What's happening, and what is the desired output?

Comment: The code is working well. The problem is that i'm trying to find a way where I could resize the image before upload it.